# Changing from magento plugin does not make effect , but changing from magento\vendor shows effect

Tags: magento, magento2

I am pretty new to Magento and using Magento 2.2.6 to develop a plugin. I need to edit the search bar. So I added a file to my plugin folder
 `Plugin \view \frontend \ templates \ form.mini.phtml` 
This does not making any changes in my website. But when I put that same file into `Magento \vendor \magento \module-search \view \frontend \templates\ form.mini.phtml` . Now I want not to any files from that vendor folder. What can I do now ? Thank you.

Comment: You are putting the file in the wrong location. maybe this helps: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-sample.html

Answer (score 0):

Block **form.mini.phtml** define in **Vendor\magento\module-search\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

```xml
<!--Vendor\magento\module-search\view\frontend\layout\default.xml -->
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Overwrite using layout in your module **app\code\VendorName\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

edit file **form.mini.phtml** and put it to **app\code\VendorName\view\frontend\templates\form.mini.phtml**

```xml
<!-- app\code\VendorName\view\frontend\layout\default.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="VendorName_ModuleName::form.mini.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can also overwrite the file in the theme without the layout file

edit file **form.mini.phtml** and put it to **app\design\frontend\Vendor\ThemeName\Magento_Search\templates\form.mini.phtml**